# How to check if object is undefined in react native?

Tags: react-native

I have an object **auth** which I am getting from onPress event from backend.
but before that I want to print ***auth._W.user.first_name** on screen if it is not undefined yet so I used and If it's undefined then print nothing

```
<Text>Welcome! 
     {auth !== undefined ? auth._W.user.first_name : null}
</Text>
```

But on compiling it's giving error

**TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'auth._W.user.first_name')**

I'm new on react native. Help me to get rid of this error.

Comment: What is the shape of the `auth` object, when it is defined?

Comment: Do this `{auth?._W?.user?.first_name ?? null}`

Comment: you can use [conditional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining), the [nullish coalesing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator), or simply use the `=== undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

You are only checking if auth is `undefined`, but not for other properties, use optional chaining with [nullish coalescing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)

```
{auth?._W?.user?.first_name ?? null}
```